# две одинакое строки, но когда сравниваю получаю ответ false

Tags: c#

в s и t значения равны, но bool res = string.Equals(s, t); всегда равно false, почему?

посмотрел в консоль и результат такой s = saba 1234?????, t = saba 1234, откуда эти ????? не понимаю

**app.config**

```
<add key="AccountsWithActiveService" value="saba {0}​​​​​" />
```

**Service**

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetSmsBankPhone()
{
    string _accountsWithActiveService = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountsWithActiveService"];
        
    string code = "1234";
    var s = string.Format(_accountsWithActiveService, code);//результат при debug "saba 1234​​​​​"
    var t = $"saba {code}"; //результат при debug "saba 1234​​​​​"
    bool res = string.Equals(s, t); //результат при debug false
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сначала вывести `s` и `t` куда-нибудь, например в консоль и там глазами проверить

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(s); System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(t); и смотрим в консоли

Comment: `string code = 1234;` - странно что вы при отладке вообще что-то получаете, потому что эта строчка не компилируется

Comment: @PashaPash исправил эту ошибку

Comment: @PashaPash, может быть включен запуск старой версии приложения при ошибке компиляции...

Comment: @PashaPash посмотрел в консоль и результат такой s = saba 1234?????, t = saba 1234, откуда эти ????? не понимаю

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(_accountsWithActiveService)

Comment: @SabaKoghuashvili смотрите посимвольно в отладке, скорее всего что-то левое неотображаемое юникодное впейстили в конфиг

Comment: `value="saba {0}​​​​​" />` поставьте курсор, например, на 0, зажмите Shift и понажимайте на стрелочку вправо: между закрывающей фигурной скобкой и кавычками присутствуют невидимые символы. Удалите их.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что на изначальный вопрос уже ответили, после чего вопрос был изменен. (да еще и плохо измен ибо разные блоки вопроса говорят о разном поведении программы, а заголовок вообще от старого вопроса)

Answer (score 4):

Причина может быть исключительно одной единственной - это ты думаешь что значения равны, а они не равны.

Т.е. одна из "одинаковых" строк имеет в себе невидимые символы.

PS: Изменять вопрос когда на него уже ответили - не очень этично по отношению к ответившим.

Comment: посмотрел в консоль и результат такой s = saba 1234?????, t = saba 1234, откуда эти ????? не понимаю

Comment: Это уже твоя парафия, я не знаю откуда ты эту строку берешь))) Соответственно дебажся и находи в чем проблема) Моя задача была показать что функция экваллс работает как нужно)